# I am not able to see my site after uploading the files to cPanel on a site hosted with GoDaddy

Tags: web, hosting, cpanel

My index.html and styles.css are both in the public_html folder, yet the site still shows the generic GoDaddy landing page.

I've tried everything I can think of, used all of cPanel's help resources and GoDaddy's as well, as well as YouTube, and a few threads on here, yet nothing has been helpful or worked.

Comment: Can you provide more information like 1. Where is your domain pointed 2. Which is the default document set in your hosting?